# Tkinter resulting in a black page when running exe version of application

Tags: python, tkinter, exe

I have created a python GUI that uses Tkinter. The GUI works perfectly when I run it from the IDE, however when I convert it to an exe format (using Pyinstaller), the exe file returns a black screen.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of the code you are trying to compile? How are you compiling it exactly?

Comment: Even the most basic code like:

Comment: import tkinter as tk

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

def hello ():  
    label1 = tk.Label(root, text= 'Hello World!', fg='green', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
    canvas1.create_window(150, 200, window=label1)
    
button1 = tk.Button(text='Click Me',command=hello, bg='brown',fg='white')
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=button1)

root.mainloop()

Comment: When I run it on Sublime text (or Jupiter or any other IDE) it works perfectly. I even tried it on a windows and it also works perfectly. However, once I run the Pyinstaller -- filename.py on terminal and open the resulting exe file in the list folder, nothing but a black screen appears

Comment: I see you what are doing is `pyinstaller -- filename.py` in the terminal. 
Suppose your file is filename.py, then it will create a folder "dist" having another folder "filename", and inside this, there you can find a "filename.exe" which works fine on my computer.

Comment: I would also suggest using `pyinstaller --onefile filename.py` to keep things simple unless you actually need every subfile.

Comment: @Kartikeya Do you have a Mac ? Cause it worked on a windows device I have at home, but when I try it on my Mac (and my sister's Mac), the resulting exe is just a black screen

Comment: For mac, refer to the documentation, for pyinstaller it's slightly different than windows:
https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#building-mac-os-x-app-bundles